# Adding variable data to column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column called `Description` which has an account number plus text ie `123456 July 2016 Statement`. There is also a column that has the account number ie `123456`.

In another table I have a reference number ie `100001234`. I want to be able to update the `Description` column to show `100001234 - 123456 July 2016 Statement`. The reference number will be different for each account number but there is ONLY 1 reference number per account.

Have tried doing REPLACE but needs 3 arguments or get

> Incorrect syntax near 'description'

Code:

```
 SELECT 
     t.[Referencenumber],
     SET [description] = (REPLACE ([Description], referencenumber + ' - ' + [Description])),
     c.[ClientID], [AccountID]
FROM 
    [Document].[dbo].[DOC.Client] AS c
INNER JOIN
    [Reporting].[dbo].[Tran] AS t ON t.Id = c.accountid
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `replace()`, but you do need an `update`.  I don't know which table has `description`:

```
update ??
    set [description] = referencenumber + ' - ' + [Description]
from [Document].[dbo].[DOC.Client] c inner join
     [Reporting].[dbo].[Tran] t
     on t.Id = c.accountid;
```